# ReactJS lifecycle data not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React app built using Redux and React and I'm fetching data using JSON. As a React is a lifecycle, should react update the fetched data automatically with no refresh if the content changed in database?
I've tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps` but that doesn't work

**src/components/layout.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; 
import { fetchUsers, postUsers, deleteUsers } from '../actions/usersAction';
import './css/styles.css';

class Layout extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        age: ''}
}

onUserUpdate(filed, event){
    if (filed === 'name') {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        });
    }
    if (filed ==='age') {
        this.setState({
            age: event.target.value
        });
    }
}
    handlePostUsers(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.postUsers(this.state.name,this.state.age);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            const nameChanged = nextProps.users !== this.props.users;
            if (nameChanged) {
                this.props.fetchUsers(nextProps)
            }
        console.log('here is componentWillReceiveProps',nextProps)
    }
  render() {
    const { act } = this.props;

      const fetchUserss = act.users.map(d =>  <tr key={d.id}><td>{d.id}</td><td>{d.name}</td><td>{d.age}</td><td><button onClick={this.props.deleteUsers.bind(this)}>Delete</button></td></tr>);
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <label>
            name:
              </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'name')} placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                <label>
                age:
              </label>
                <input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'age')} placeholder="enter username"/>
                <button onClick={(e) => this.handlePostUsers(e)}>Add News</button>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>AGE</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 {fetchUserss}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        act: state.users,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchUsers, postUsers, deleteUsers}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

[image]

Please let me know if I miss out any information.

If this has already been asked, I would greatly appreciate if you are able to point me in the right direction.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake in your code is that in `componentWillReceiveProps` you are comparing `nextProps.users` vs `this.props.users` however, `users` is not a prop to the component, its `act`, change your `componentWillReceiveProps` to

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const nameChanged = nextProps.act.name !== this.props.act.name || nextProps.act.age !== this.props.act.age;
        if (nameChanged) {
            this.props.fetchUsers(nextProps)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed it to act but it keeps refreshing.

Comment: So act is an object right?, in that case  equality check fails, you need to compare individual keys

Comment: I've tried to change it to nextProps.act.users !== this.props.act.users it works fine but it keeps refreshing and the site going very slow any tips please

Comment: Make sure the that fetchUsers is being called at approriate time, also look into PureComponent

Answer (score 0):

rename act to users

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    users: state.users,
};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it should work if I do this way you provided but I have to change all my act to users, I prefer to just change users to act in componentWillReceiveProps